# Firefox upgrade 51.0.1 Broken (Renders blank screens)

Tags: apt, firefox

After running Software update utility, I got the dialog asking to restart Firefox. Upon restarting firefox, It renders a blank screen.

The address bar, menus, toolbars etc. are visible. I can open tabs, windows, etc. Page Icons are rendered in the tabs. Just a blank screen as if no html was sent.

dpkg.log doesn't show any discrepancies:

```
2017-01-29 08:34:18 configure firefox:amd64 51.0.1+build2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 <none>
2017-01-29 08:34:18 status unpacked firefox:amd64 51.0.1+build2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
2017-01-29 08:34:18 status unpacked firefox:amd64 51.0.1+build2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
2017-01-29 08:34:18 status unpacked firefox:amd64 51.0.1+build2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
2017-01-29 08:34:18 status unpacked firefox:amd64 51.0.1+build2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
2017-01-29 08:34:18 status unpacked firefox:amd64 51.0.1+build2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
2017-01-29 08:34:18 status half-configured firefox:amd64 51.0.1+build2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
2017-01-29 08:34:20 status installed firefox:amd64 51.0.1+build2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
```

The internal page: "about:config" renders fine and has the following link to the compiler flags used to build the version:

https://hg.mozilla.org/releases/mozilla-release/rev/84fc5992d31fcb9b26c92bb0054db164720d7fbe

Comment: have you tested uninstalling firefox, purging the files of configuration and making it to install?

Comment: Are you using Firefox profiles for apparmor ?

Comment: Looking at this comment from Mozilla: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1334748#c7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the linked comment above to bugzilla.mozilla.org solved the issue. From that comment:

> In bug 1659988, in the 3rd patch file of
>   `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.firefox`, if you change the line (70):
>
> ```
> owner /dev/shm/org.chromium.* c,
> ```
>
> to
>
> ```
> owner /dev/shm/org.chromium.* rw,
> ```
>
> Apply it to `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.firefox`
>
> Then, `sudo apparmor_parser -r /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.firefox`
>   That is, the patch file:

```
36a37,39
>   dbus (send)
>        bus=session
>        interface=org.gtk.vfs.MountTracker,
44a48
>   @{PROC}/[0-9]*/net/arp r,
65c69,70
<   owner /{,var/}run/shm/shmfd-* rw,
---
>   owner /{dev,{,var/}run}/shm/shmfd-* rw,
>   owner /dev/shm/org.chromium.* rw,
206a212
>     /usr/share/distro-info/debian.csv r,
209a216
>     /usr/include/python3.[0-5]/pyconfig.h r,
214c221
<     /usr/local/lib/python3.[0-4]/dist-packages/ r,
---
>     /usr/local/lib/python3.[0-5]/dist-packages/ r,
216c223
<     /usr/bin/python3.[0-4] r,
---
>     /usr/bin/python3.[0-5] r,
```

So, copy the above file (no changes needed) to `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.firefox.patch` and run the following:

```
$ sudo chown root:root /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.firefox.patch
$ sudo patch usr.bin.firefox usr.bin.firefox.patch
$ sudo apparmor_parser -r /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.firefox
```

Now, you restart firefox and you should be good.